# How to fix the index of duplicate in a list

Tags: python, list, indexing, duplicates, element

I want to make a list that can store up the index of list a according to decreasing value

this is my code:

```
a = [1,2,2,6,7]
b = deepcopy(a)
b.sort(reverse = True)
position = []

for counter in range(len(a)):
   position_highest = b[counter]
   position_fit = a.index(position_highest)
   position.append(position_fit)

print(position)
```

The code gave me a result like this
[4,3,1,1,0]

can I know how to handle the duplicate so that I can get a result in a list like this
[4,3,1,2,0]

Comment: Would `[4,3,2,1,0]` also be valid?

Comment: yes, either one

Comment: `[y for _, y in sorted((x[::-1] for x in enumerate(a)), reverse=True)]`

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been stuck here all day TT. You are such a savior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Return Value from List index()
The index() method returns the index of the given element in the list.
If the element is not found, a ValueError exception is raised.
Note: The index() method only returns the first occurrence of the matching element.(https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index)"

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/

```
import copy

a = [1,2,2,6,7]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
b.sort(reverse = True)
position = []


arr=[]
for i in enumerate(b):# a[7, 6, 2, 2, 1]
    ''' 
    ind val
    (0, 7)
    (1, 6)
    (2, 2)
    (3, 2)
    (4, 1)
    '''
    arr.append(i[0])
position=arr[::-1]
'''
a=  [1,2,2,6,7]
ind=[0,1,2,3,4]
reverse ...
b=   [7,6,2,2,1]
ind= [0,1,2,3,4]
reverse ...
resul=[4,3,2,1]
'''

print(position)
```